# Python Pillow decreasing image brightness changes background

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to change image brightness with Python's Pillow (Pillow.ImageEnhance). My images are products on white background (JPEG, RGB) and I want it to remain white regardless of brightness changes.

When decreasing brightness with Pillow background turns off-white, while if I do the same thing in Photoshop, background stays white.

Is there any way to preserve white background in Pillow?

Comment: You could look into flood fill for background removal, so that the new image  will contain only the object you want to enhance. Then simply add the background back.

Comment: If only your background is white you could create a binary mask beforehand and apply it again after adapting the brightness.